# Why can't I retrieve my uploaded file or body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, zip

So, I am working on an already made express app and I am to write an upload api that receives the zip and an email. The problem I am having is that both req.body.email and req.file are undefined on the server. I have tested using the form-data body section on postman and even with a simple html form. I would like the know if the issue is with the code or with testing.

Here is the already made server.js

```
// Node.js core dependencies
require('dotenv').config();

// Npm dependencies
const express = require('express');
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
const compression = require('compression');
const cors = require('cors');
var useragent = require('express-useragent');
const uuid = require('uuid');
const pinoHttpLogger = require('pino-http');
const promBundle = require('express-prom-bundle');
const bp = require('body-parser');
const metricsMiddleware = promBundle({
  buckets: [0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 3, 5, 7.5, 10, 12.5, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 60],
  includeMethod: true,
  includePath: true,
  includeStatusCode: true,
  promClient: { collectDefaultMetrics: {} }
});


// Local dependencies
const router = require('./app/router');
const noCache = require('./common/utils/no-cache');
const correlationHeader = require('./common/middleware/correlation-header');
const { logger, PinoLogger } = require('./app/utils/logger');

// Global constants
const unconfiguredApp = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const { NODE_ENV } = process.env;

function initialiseGlobalMiddleware(app) {
  app.use(compression());

  if (process.env.DISABLE_REQUEST_LOGGING !== 'true') {
    app.use(
      pinoHttpLogger({
        logger: PinoLogger,
        genReqId: (req) => req.headers['x-request-id'] || uuid(),
        autoLogging: {
          ignorePaths: ['/metrics', '/healthcheck', '/'],
          ignore: (req) => req.method === 'OPTIONS'
        },
        serializers: {
          req(request) {
            return {
              url: request.url,
              method: request.method,
              reqId: request.id,
              params: request.params,
              query: request.query,
              headers: {
                host: request.headers.host,
                origin: request.headers.origin,
                referer: request.headers.referer,
                'user-agent': request.headers['user-agent'],
                'x-forwarded-for': request.headers['x-forwarded-for']
              }
            };
          },
          res(response) {
            return { statusCode: response.statusCode };
          },
          err: pinoHttpLogger.serializers
        }
      })
    );
  }
app.use(bp.json());
app.use(bp.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.asset_path = '/public/'; // eslint-disable-line camelcase
    noCache(res);
    next();
  });

  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.originalUrl === '/stripe-webhook') {
      next();
    } else {
      express.json({ limit: '10mb' })(req, res, next);
    }
  });

  app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }));
  app.use(cors());
  app.use('*', correlationHeader);
  app.use(useragent.express());
  app.use(metricsMiddleware);
}

function initialiseProxy(app) {
  app.enable('trust proxy');
}

function initialiseRoutes(app) {
  router.bind(app);
}

function listen() {
  const app = initialise();
  app.listen(PORT);
  logger.info('Listening on port ' + PORT);
}

/**
 * Configures app
 * @return app
 */
function initialise() {
  console.log('## ENVIRONMENT ##', process.env.NODE_ENV);

  const app = unconfiguredApp;
  app.disable('x-powered-by');
  initialiseProxy(app);
  initialiseGlobalMiddleware(app);
  initialiseRoutes(app);

  return app;
}

/**
 * Starts app after ensuring DB is up
 */
function start() {
  listen();
}

/**
 * -i flag. Immediately invoke start.
 * Allows script to be run by task runner
 */
if (argv.i) {
  start();
}

process.on('unhandledRejection', (error) => {
  logger.error({ error }, 'Unhandled Promise Rejection');
});

module.exports = {
  start,
  getApp: initialise
};
```

AND here is the upload.js API. Just a simple console.log

```
const upload = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const file = req.files && req.files.file;
    const { email } = req.body;
    console.log('Email:', email);
    console.log('File:', file);
    console.log(req.body);
    if (!file) {
      return res.status(400).send(`No file uploaded ${email}`);
    }

    console.log(`File received for email ${email}`);

    // Return the response
    return res.status(200).send(`File received for email ${email}`);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  } finally {
    fs.unlinkSync(req.file);
  }
};

module.exports = upload;
```

HOW I AM TESTING

I have a lightweight html file for testing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Upload Form</h1>
    <form action="http://localhost:8000/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br><br>
      <label for="file">File:</label>
      <input type="file" id="file" name="file" required><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Even after attaching a file and entering an email, The response is

```
No file uploaded undefined
```

On the terminal, all the console.logs show

```
Email: undefined
File: undefined
{} --- (For req.body)
```

Same thing when I use the postman form-data (body) section of postman.

[image: Postman]

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? It's driving me crazy